# SQL To delete number of items is less than required item number

Tags: sql, .net

I have two tables - StepModels (support plan) and FeedbackStepModels (feedback), StepModels keeps how many steps each support plan requires.

```
 SELECT [SupportPlanID],COUNT(*)AS Steps
 FROM [StepModels]
 GROUP BY SupportPlanID

 SupportPlanID    (Steps)
 -------------------------------
      1              4 
      2              9
      3              3 
      4             10
```

FeedbackStepModels keeps how many steps employee entered the system

```
  SELECT [FeedbackID],SupportPlanID,Count(*)AS StepsNumber
  FROM [FeedbackStepModels]
  GROUP BY FeedbackID,SupportPlanID

   FeedbackID    SupportPlanID
 ---------------------------------------------
      1              1             3  --> this suppose to be 4
      2              2             9  --> Correct
      3              3             0  --> this suppose to be 3
      4              4             10  --> Correct
```

If submitted Feedback steps total is less then required total amount I want to delete this wrong entry from the database. Basically i need to delete FeedbackID 1 and 3.

I can load the data into List and compare and delete it, but want to know if we can we do this in SQL rather than C# code.

Comment: Yes, you can do it in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query below to remove your unwanted data by SQL Script

```
DELETE f
FROM FeedbackStepModels f
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT [FeedbackID],SupportPlanID, Count(*) AS StepsNumber
   FROM [FeedbackStepModels]
   GROUP BY FeedbackID,SupportPlanID
) f_derived on f_derived_FeedbackID=f.FeedBackID and f_derived.SupportPlanID = f.SupportPlanID
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT [SupportPlanID],COUNT(*)AS Steps
   FROM [StepModels]
   GROUP BY SupportPlanID
) s_derived on s_derived.SupportPlanID = f.SupportPlanID 
WHERE f_derived.StepsNumber < s_derived.Steps
```

Comment: Rica ederim, sagolasin. You are welcome. Actually our answers are similar, He uses IN (...) instead of another inner join.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this.

```
DELETE FROM [FeedbackStepModels]
WHERE FeedbackID IN
(
    SELECT a.FeedbackID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [FeedbackID], 
               SupportPlanID, 
               COUNT(*) AS StepsNumber
        FROM [FeedbackStepModels]
        GROUP BY FeedbackID, 
                 SupportPlanID
    ) AS a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT [SupportPlanID], 
               COUNT(*) AS Steps
        FROM [StepModels]
        GROUP BY SupportPlanID
    ) AS b ON a.SupportPlanID = b.[SupportPlanID]
    WHERE a.StepsNumber < b.Steps
);
```

Comment: Thank you ClearLogic. Actually your answer is more clearer and easy to read. But he replied first and i am only allow to chose one answer.